# Adding multiple indexes at same time in MySQL

Tags: mysql, indexing

During tests on MySQL, I wanted to add multiple indexes to a table with more than 50 million rows. Does MySQL support adding 2 indexes at the same time for different columns? If yes, Do I need to open 2 sessions or it can be done from one command?

Answer (score 26):

Yes.  But...

In older versions, use

```
ALTER TABLE tbl
    ADD INDEX(...),
    ADD INDEX(...);
```

so that it will do all the work in one pass.

In newer versions, `ALGORITHM=INPLACE` makes it so that the work can be done in the "background" for InnoDB tables, thereby having less impact on other processing.  However, to get the `INPLACE` processing, you may need to add each index separately.  *[Check the manual for the specific syntax; there have been many changes in the 6+ years since I wrote this Answer.  Also, MySQL and MariaDB are not in lock-step.]*

The  <strike>[Ref manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html) [ref manual]</strike> [Ref manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html) lists some caveats, such as dealing with `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: Good to know. An additional info i want to know is if we want to modify a column to become primary key auto_increment , does the following command assure us that the auto_increment starts at the first record: ALTER TABLE table1 modify column content_id bigint(20)  AUTO_INCREMENT  primary key; ?

Comment: Adding a PRIMARY KEY _requires_ rewriting the table (the slow method).  Yes, you can (should, for speed) do everything in a single `ALTER`:  `ALTER TABLE tbl MODIFY ... ADD PRIMARY KEY (...), ADD INDEX ..., etc;`

Comment: If `content_id` already has data in it, are you adding `AUTO_INCREMENT` and `PRIMARY KEY`?  Is it already `BIGINT`?  (Please show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE`)

Comment: CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `content_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL ,
  `pid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `datecreated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `datemodified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: How big is the table?  What is `MAX(content_id)`?  What is your tentative `ALTER`, based on the advice so far?

Answer (score 3):

It is useful to create it in the time of the table creation, which can be done like this:

```
CREATE TABLE name_of_a_new_table (col1 variable_type_1, col2 variable_type_2,
       INDEX idx_col1 (col1), INDEX idx_col2 (col2));
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked the MySQL manual? InnoDB supports fast index creation, and maybe it is what you are looking for:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-create-index.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, i will test that and come back with a response.

Comment: @Peter Mortensen: I submitted the edit request with fixed URL, I don't see that entry in my activity anymore. What happened?