# use Foreign key indexes in multi index mysql

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have A table with almost 20 fields which several of those are Foreign Key that already has been indexed by Mysql, now I want to create a multi-indexes index that it contains 3 FK field, 
First tried was based on Fields

```
ALTER TABLE `Add`
    Add INDEX `IX_Add_ON_IDCat_IDStatus_IDModeration_DateTo_DateAdded` 
       (`IDCategory`,`IDStatus`,`IDModeration`,`DateTo`,`DateAdded`);
```

But I think it's better to have an index on indexes instead of fields but my following effort faced with error: `Error Code: 1072. Key column 'FK_Add_Category' doesn't exist in table`

```
ALTER TABLE `Add`
    Add INDEX `IX_Add_ON_IDCat_IDStatus_IDModeration_DateTo_DateAdded`
        (`FK_Add_Category`,`FK_Add_AddStatus`,`FK_Add_AddModeration`,
         `IX_Add_DateTo`,`IX_Add_DateAdded`);
```

**My question is is it possible to add an index on exists Indexes ( FK index in my case ) or not and there is the only way to create an index on Columns? if yes How I create that?**

Comment: *have an index on indexes* - that is not possible.

Comment: You can index on table name (index column name) , an index is not a column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding multiple indexes at same time in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627258/adding-multiple-indexes-at-same-time-in-mysql)

Comment: What is the question?  The first statement is the right thing to do in MySQL.

Comment: @juergend thanks, I'm looking for it in MySQL, it's possible in Oracle .

Comment: @Dr.Geek thank you for attention but my question is about an index on indexes.

Comment: @GordonLinoff my question is about an index on indexes that I find out myself not support it yet.

Comment: @zhilevan . . . There is no "yet".  "Index on index" does not make sense in a SQL context.

Comment: @zhilevan - do you have a link to Oracle's use of it?  _This I gotta see!_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An index is an ordered list of values.  It is used to make it more efficient to find rows in the table.

Think about the common, real-life, example of `INDEX(last_name, first_name)`.  It makes it easy to look up someone if you have their last name and first name.  And sort of easy if you have only their last name.

But it is useless if all you have is their first name.

`FOREIGN KEYs` necessitate a lookup.  Apparently you have a FK to `AddStatus`, since I see `FK_Add_AddStatus`.  That FK generated a lookup for `AddStatus`.  Think of that as being like a *separate* index on `first_name`.  It is totally separate from the index on `last_name` & `first_name`.

5 columns is usually too many to put into a single index.

MySQL uses only one index for a given `SELECT`.

So, now, I ask, what `SELECT` might use that 5-column index?  Please show us it.  We can discuss whether it is useful, and whether the columns are in the optimal order.