# MYSQL INDEX FOR Multiple where columns combinations?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

Please help to make Mysql index For multiple where conditions Example **:**

```
Select id from table_name where col1='' and col2='' and col3='' and col4=''
and col5=''and col6='';
```

Now number of combinations of where conditions ,First two columns `col1` and `col2` is fix ; other combinations IS:-

```
where col1='' and col2='' and col3='' ;

where col1='' and col2='' and col3='' and col4='';

where col1='' and col2='' and col3='' and col4=''and col5='';

where col1='' and col2='' and col5=''and col6='';

where col1='' and col2='' and col4=''and col5=''and col6='';

where col1='' and col2='' and col4='' and col6=''

where col1='' and col2='' and col4='';

where col1='' and col2='' and col5='';

where col1='' and col2='' and col6='';

where col1='' and col2='' and col3='' and col5='';
```

I have only one Index

```
create INDEX `allpair` ON TABLE_NAME (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6);
```

**Please Help to make what is proper index for according these all where combinations. Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Your index `allpair` will not cover every one of the queries in your list.  If you have a composite index on `(col1, col2, col3)`, then only where clauses on `col1`, `(col1, col2)`, or `(col1, col2, col3)` will use the index.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen sir please show indexs and  let me explain about it

Comment: I have no indices to "show" you unfortunately, I only commented to say that your composite index _won't_ cover all the queries you mentioned.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen thn sir which index work for these conditions please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following column combinations would cover all your queries (I have removed the `col` prefix for simplicity):

```
 1  2  3 

 1  2  3  4

 1  2  3  4  5

 1  2  5  6

 1  2  4  5  6

 1  2  4  6

 1  2  4

 1  2  5

 1  2  6

 1  2  3  5
```

However, there are some indexes that cover more than one of the queries. For example, the index `1 2 3 4 5` already covers `1 2 3` and `1 2 3 4` because those columns are included in the leftmost part of the `1 2 3 4 5` index.

Thus, the column combinations you need would remove from the original list those elements which are leftmost contained in bigger elements:

```
 1  2  3  4  5

 1  2  5  6

 1  2  4  5  6

 1  2  4  6

 1  2  6

 1  2  3  5
```

Comment: how to cover other 

 1  2  5  6 ,  

 1  2  4  5  6  ,

 1  2  4  6  ,

 1  2  6  ,

 1  2  3  5

Comment: You would need to add a new index by combination, unless the combination is already present in any of the existing indexes, starting from the left. Take into account that, for example, if you already have index `1 2 6` and you need to add index `1 2 6 5`, the old one becomes dispensable.

Comment: sir im litle bit confused how to make other index ,i try some index (12456), but for other please help

Comment: Do you mean yo do not know how to make several indexes in a single table?

Comment: You can have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627258/adding-multiple-indexes-at-same-time-in-mysql

Comment: Actually i don't understand your last number of list that you would separate from original list. Elements..I'm confused there

Comment: Means these 4 indexs cover all where combinations ..  Index1 (1,2,3,4,5)  ,   index2 (1,2,6,5) ,,, index3 (1,2,4,5,6)  ,,, index4 (1,2,3,5)     is am i right?  Please let me know sir